# Routing with AngularJS and Express

Tags: angularjs, express, routes

I am trying to use AngularJS `ngRoute` along side Express but I keep getting the following error:

> cannot Get /profile

Here's my code:

```
.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/profile', {
        templateUrl: 'views/partials/profile.html',
        controller: 'kontrola'
      })

      $locationProvider.html5Mode('true')
      $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!')



    app.get('/', routes.index)
    app.get('/login', routes.login)
    app.get('/signup', routes.signup)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular's `ngRoute` is for client-side routing, while express is for server-side routing.

You will need to set a handler in your server to serve static files, like this (assuming your `views` folder is in the `static` folder:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'static'));
```

Then when you go to `http://yourservername/#/profile` you will get your profile view.

if you want to use `html5mode` you need to have a tag like this:

```
<head>
   .....
    <base href="/">

</head>
```

Comment: thanks Shimon for reply but i tried to moving the partial file to the views folder, set the  handler on the server like
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'static')); and navigated to localhost/3000/#/profile but it remain in the current index page and changing the url to http://localhost:3000/#!#%2Fprofile instead and as you can see am trying to avoid the #! in the url that's why i use the $locationProvider but still appearing

Comment: So you are not getting the `cannot Get /profile` anymore, right?

Comment: so now it's only an angular issue, what version of angular are you using?

Comment: am using the following versions: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.js"></script>

Comment: Let me edit my answer, and please accept it, if I was helpful.

Comment: sure. it only works when i type localhost/3000/#!/profile directly

Comment: Even after adding your `base` tag?

Comment: yes. i have added the base tag right from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', '$provide', function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {

```
  $routeProvider.when('/profile', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/pro.html',
    controller: 'kontrola'
  })
```

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!')

```
}])
```

instead of:

.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', '$provide', function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!')

```
  $routeProvider.when('/profile', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/pro.html',
    controller: 'kontrola'
  })
```